# Redirect all requests if condition satisfied using middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

- I have an instance of expressjs server running that serves an SPA.
- My API lives on another server so I need to bounce my API requests.
- I want to create a middleware that redirects all those requests to another host if it meets a certain condition.
- The requests that are gonna be handled are the ones with `target: API` in the request headers

so far this is how my middleware looks like and I am able to capture selected request which meets the condition:

```
function apiHelmet(req, res, next) {
    if (req.get('target') === 'API') {
        /*
            find a way to redirect requests of all methods and pipe result to response
        */
        return res.send(response_from_external_api)
    }
    return next()
}
```

my setup:

```
app.use(apiHelmet)
app.get('*', renderSPA)
```

example post request:

```javascript
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    data: { id: 123, first_name: 'john', last_name: 'doe' },
    url: '/users',
    headers: {
        target: 'API'
    }

} ).then(result=>console.log(result))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? A express route middleware would look like 'the/url/path/', middleware1, middleware2, (req, res) => {})

Comment: please see my edit @noa-dev

Comment: In my experience it's more common to use a path (`/api`) than a header, then you can just drop in an existing tool like https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware (I think you could use this anyway with a custom matching filter, but path is simpler).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Call another External API using request module and pipe External API response directly to Your server response.

```
var request = require('request');

app.use(apiHelmet)
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    req.pipe(request('SOME URL').on('error', function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err)
    })).pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily using following code.

```
function apiHelmet(req, res, next) {
    if (req.get('target') === 'API') {
        return res.send('caught ya')
        req.post({url: 'http://end-point', headers: req.headers, body: req.body});
        processRequest(req);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send('Req OK');
    }
    return next()
}
```

For more details [see](https://github.com/request/request).